# How can I get pymongo to always return str and not unicode?

Tags: pymongo

From the pymongo docs:

> MongoDB stores data in BSON format. BSON strings are UTF-8 encoded so PyMongo must ensure
>   that any strings it stores contain only valid UTF-8 data. Regular strings () are > validated and stored unaltered. Unicode strings () are encoded UTF-8 first. > The reason our example string is represented in the Python shell as u’Mike’ instead of 
>   ‘Mike’ is that PyMongo decodes each BSON string to a Python unicode string, not a regular 
>   str."

It seems a bit silly to me that the database can only store UTF-8 encoded strings, but the return type in pymongo is unicode, meaning the first thing I have to do with every string from the document is once again call encode('utf-8') on it.  Is there some way around this, i.e. telling pymongo not to give me unicode back but just give me the raw str?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: I am working with several libraries that only work on encoded strings, e.g. bcrypt. It's nice to be able to make the guarantee to the developers of my project that all of the data they are working with is going to be strings, instead of having to add in a whole lot of type checking.

Comment: The problem is in "just the raw str". Since it is unicode there can be characters there that can't be represented as a str. So a lib level conversion is not feasible. I would just tell your devs that everything they will get is u"" and that they have to convert it... That also saves you the overhead of unnecessary conversions.

Comment: The first sentence from the UTF-8 wikipedia entry: "UTF-8 (UCS Transformation Format—8-bit[1]) is a variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set." So, in fact, all of unicode can certainly be represented by a raw string using UTF-8 encoding. We aren't really getting at the problem I asked about.

Comment: Do keep in mind that UTF-8 is a implementation encoding of unicode and for all purposes here: UTF-8 == unicode. So what you get here is coherent. A raw string of unicode chars == the `unicode` type in python, not `str`. This is because **`str`** can **only** represent **asci** characters and certainly **not** all **unicode** [characters](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: s = u'hello' ; type(s.encode('utf-8'))  Type that into your REPL; you'll clearly see that the unicode type has been encoded down to a str. You can represent any byte sequence as a Python str type, which is the equivalent of a char* in C; that's the fundamental difference between unicode and UTF-8 that you don't seem to fully understand. Unicode is not a sequence of bytes; UTF-8 is a way to represent unicode as a sequence of bytes, a.k.a. a str type. In any case, my question was just where is a good place in cherrypy to do the encoding so I wouldn't have to repeat myself.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you understand: Call "dir(u'x')" and then call "dir('x')". You will see similar API's, but definitely not the exact same. Since they aren't the same, if you don't know exactly which type you're dealing with, you don't know if you can call some methods on that variable, so you'll end up doing a type check. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: One reason to want this is to reduce memory footprint. `unicode` takes around four times the amount of memory than `str` in most european language settings. For applications that process huge amounts of language data this makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such feature in PyMongo; every string decoded from BSON is decoded as UTF-8. Python represents the string internally as UCS-2 or some other format, depending on the Python version. See the [code where the BSON decoder extracts a string](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/2fa1750b07e5f21ea4b67330e6266f2db1588e89/bson/__init__.py#L105).

In the upcoming PyMongo 3.x series we may add features for more flexible BSON decoding to allow developers to optimize uncommon use cases like this.