# Inserting string as regular string in mongodb

Tags: pymongo

The pymongo documentation says that BSON strings are UTF-8 encoded so PyMongo must ensure that any strings it stores contain only valid UTF-8 data. Unicode strings (`<type ‘unicode’>`) are encoded UTF-8 first. The reason our example string is represented in the Python shell as u’Mike’ instead of ‘Mike’ is that PyMongo decodes each BSON string to a Python unicode string, not a regular str.

So I understand that to get rid of the Unicode literal 'u', I will have to call `json.dumps()` on the document returned by the query.

The documentation also says that Regular strings (`<type ‘str’>`) are validated and stored unaltered. And I am assuming that the query result also throws it back as a regular string and not a Unicode string.

I created a dictionary with regular string types and inserted it in DB and when I retrieve it, I get the strings as Unicode. Any idea on how do I do it? The purpose is to avoid calling `json.dumps()` on the query result. I need to fetch large number of documents from the DB and `json.dumps()` is taking quite some time. The strings that I am storing contain ASCII data so I don't need Unicode strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that the regular string is returned back as regular string was not correct. It is stored unaltered and not encoded to UTF-8 because it is already UTF-8. While decoding during the query, everything is converted back to Unicode.

Source:

- [Automatic string to unicode object conversion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/unicode$20string/mongodb-user/f5n50R7X3oc/muGDgLfn2BUJ)
- [How can I get pymongo to always return str and not unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103497/how-can-i-get-pymongo-to-always-return-str-and-not-unicode)